# view has no constraints

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

some of my methods aren't getting hit and i've come to the possible conclusion it has to do with my constraints

these are a few methods not getting hit

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView)->Int {
    print("not hit1")

    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->   Int {
    print("not hit either")

    return  self.funlists.count;
    //return 1
}
```

when i go to storyboard and click on the uitableview it says there are no constraints. When i go to editor, the add missing constraints is an unclickable option.

Comment: Have you setup your tableview datasource and delegate methods to file owner controller?

Comment: @Mrunal, thanks for the help! In regards to datasource and delagete, all i've done is include ->       class viewUniversityList: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {,            how would i setup those two methods to a file owner controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraints decides the position of your tableview,not function executes or not.

Try

```
yourtableview.dataSource = self
youttableview.delegate = self
```

If you want to XCode to auto add missing constraints,first you have to select the tableview in storybaord

Comment: If you have another question,you would better to open a new question. Not update the old one.